# Condenser OK for vocals?

Tags: microphone

I play in an Irish band.I use a condensed mic for my accordion. Occasionally I have to sing without playing my instrument. Will the condenser mic be OK for singing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could easily be answered by a google search.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, yes many people use condenser microphones for vocal. Generically, condenser microphones may be more sensitive and have a flatter frequency response than your typical rock-style dynamic microphone, so you might want to experiment to see if you would like to make any EQ changes, etc. when using your instrumental condenser mic for vocals.

Answer (score 0):

Depends entirely on the type of condensor mic you are planning on using. If you are going to use a condensor mic, use one that is specifically designed for vocals. If you don't you are likely to experience a lot of clipping due to wind and possibly movement if the mic becomes hand-held.

If you are using an instrument condensor, i.e. a cardioid condensor I do not recommend using this for vocals. At the very least you will need some sort of wind protection on the mic.

A static cardioid condensor on the accordion will not be subject to the wind and movement issues that you will have if you use if for vocals.

Remember that condensor cardioids are subject to proximity effect which increases the effect of wind and close vocals.

Overall, I would recommend using a dedicated vocals mic for vocals and leave the condensor on the accordion.

Comment: btw, all cardioids have proximity effect. I kind of like where you're going with this answer, but I don't think it's complete. A nice little DPA 1060 would be lovely on an accordion & could quite easily be swapped to a vox mic with little effort, so long as [as designed] it was out of the 'breathing line'. A 20 dollar copy could be OK on accordion live, at a push, but you wouldn't dream of using it for vox unless you were doing interviews for YouTube.

Comment: Yes. That's what I said. "Condensor cardioids are subject to proximity effect". I didn't say "some cardioids". Can you point to a link to a DPA 1060? Not sure they make a 1060.

Comment: Sorry, my bad; misremembered, had to dig in my mic case to find it... 4060 not 1060 http://www.dpamicrophones.com/microphones/dscreet/4060-miniature-omnidirectional-microphone-hi-sens - idk whether it's the *best* all-round lav mic, but it's the one I've managed to use successfully on the largest variety of sources.

Comment: OK so for performance purposes you would _not_ use a lavalier mic on an instrument and then pick it up and use it for performance vocals. That's just nope.

Comment: It's all just 'nope'. The real 'fix' is buy a second mic, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If its live and an intimate crowd the room may be hearing audio direct from the source and only be being reinforced by the foh mix ....and to be honest i have used different types of mics precisely in situations that they are suggested not to be used in and things have turned out ok ...... Try it ....If it sounds ok go with it ...if it doesnt then go for something else....in the end its whether it sounds ok or not and i have used some pretty cheap ass mics and got an ok sound

Dont let anyone talk you into spending money on more gear unless you have tried what you have already....to rule out a mic without even trying it just seems a lil crazy....If you read up on the beatles they were famous for going into a studio and pulling things apart and using them in ways the designers had never intended them to be used ....I follow their example and always look for a new way of using equipment in situations it was never intended for...
As for mics i like a sm58  you can use them for instruments or to mic up a cabinet or for vocal but thats because my gear gets dragged al over the place and the 58s are bulletproof....maybe not the best sound you can get out of a mic but with a few amps and a bit of eq you can usually get a decent sound.